# what wrong with linq query select condition

Tags: asp.net

getting error in my linq query code below:

```
var imgfoldernme=from  ct in db.ShopAssignDetails.OrderByDescending(m=>m.Id).Where(c=>c.CompanyId.ToString()==sh.Cid.ToString() && c.BrandId.ToString()==sh.BId.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: i got answer below so please do not push down arrow

Answer (score 1):

Try, you didn't write exact error message so there may be more errors than what we see, this:

```
var imgfoldernme = db.ShopAssignDetails
    .OrderByDescending(m=>m.Id)
    .Where(c => c.CompanyId.ToString() == sh.Cid.ToString() && c.BrandId.ToString() == sh.BId.ToString())
    .ToList();
```

Problem is you're trying to use both syntax for LINQ queries. You started to write a query expression (`from ... in ...`) but actually you didn't provide anything else (calls to `OrderByDescending` and `Where` will feed `from` data source). For a query expression you have at least to provide a `select` statement too.

Answer (score 0):

you are using linq query syntax and lambda expression at once

use this

```
var imgfoldernme = db.ShopAssignDetails
.OrderByDescending(m=>m.Id)
.Where(c => c.CompanyId.ToString() == sh.Cid.ToString() && c.BrandId.ToString() == sh.BId.ToString())
.ToList();
```